# OPENGL ES 2 cube texture

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I've got big problems with aplicating texture to cube using OpenGL ES 2 on Android. I want to use same texture for each side of cube. Now I am drawing only two sides, but it is behaving very weird. Because I am not a native English speaker and it's difficult for me to descibed it I recorder a video where you can see what's happening. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mYLzu28p4bs&feature=youtu.be

```
private float[] vertices = {
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, //0
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, //1
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, //2
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, //3            
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, //4
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, //5
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, //6
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f  //7 
     };
private float texture[] = {         
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f,         
        1.0f, 1.0f,         
        2.0f, 0.0f,
        2.0f, 1.0f          
};
private final short order[] = {         
                       0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3,
                       3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 5

                /*     5, 4, 6, 5, 6, 7,
                       7, 6, 1, 7, 1, 0,
                       0, 3, 5, 0, 5, 7,
                       1, 2, 4, 1, 4, 6*/       
                       };
```

I'd be very grateful, can't find solution :/ thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

Weird?  Well, can't say I know what you mean by weird, but it just looks like you don't have depth testing on (causing that face to overlap the other when it shouldn't be) and are not culling faces (your faces are CW)?

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glFrontFace(GL_CW);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
```